# How can I check if two squares intersect?

Tags: math, geometry

square1 = (47,15) (51,15) (51,19) (47,19)

square2 = (19,0) (-27,46) (19,92) (65,46)

These two squares may not be parallel to X axis or Y axis.

These two squares do not intersect, but how can I find it mathematically from those points?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrarily rotated squares you can use [Separating Axes Theorem](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf) (SAT) method. [One more explanation](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/).

It checks whether the first convex polygon lies outer of all sides of the second one and vice versa. This method is quite effective.

Answer (score 0):

For cases when edges are parallel to Y and Y axes you can use following (in simple form, without performance optimization):

```
(min(square2.x1, square2.x2) <= max(square1.x1, square1.x2)) and
(min(square1.x1, square1.x2) <= max(square2.x1, square2.x2)) and
(min(square2.y1, square2.y2) <= max(square1.y1, square1.y2)) and
(min(square1.y1, square1.y2) <= max(square2.y1, square2.y2))
```

Comment: These two squares may not be parallel to X axis or Y axis.

Comment: Then this condition above defines a precondition. If this condition returns *false*, there is definitely no intersection. If *true*, further checks are needed. Check if diagonals of one square intersect with edges of another one and vice versa. If still no intersection, check if diagonals of the 2nd square intersect with edges of the 1st one. Still no intersection? Then check if one of them is completely inside of another one.